# Can one see static forces in Blender?

Tags: physics

I have just started with Blender and normally I would dig into the manual first (so far I have done little more than do the ginger bread man tutorial). But this month I have to do an assignment for which I want to see the forces acting inside a model under a static load (a hook with a coat hanging on it) and I was wondering if I could do this with Blender.

I have briefly looked through the physics section of the manual. I don't quite understand all of it yet, but what I gathered so far is that weight is not physical weight but the number of vertices (so in a way the complexity of the model), particles aren't physical particles and physics only works for fluids. Is that correct?
And the static physics section doesn't seem to cover it either.

Comment: forget blender for this job, it has 0 tools for such visualizations.

Comment: Well.. You *might* be able to do something with soft bodies, but blender really isn't made to do this kind of thing.